# How to add new field(s) and records to the call logs(call history) database?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a VoIP application and I wanted to know if it is possible to do the following with the Call Logs content provider -

1. I want to add new Call Log records for the VoIP call along with the call logs for the regular call. How can I add new records to the existing Call logs content provider?
2. I want to add custom fields to the Call Logs like a session ID and SIP    address(name@domain) field. How can I customize the call logs database?

It'll be great if someone can give me an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a standard SDK application, you cannot directly extend or modify the `CallLog` database or content provider. For an SDK-based VOIP application, you should maintain your own call log.

If you are writing your own firmware for your own device, I am sure there are ways you can modify the call log database.

Comment: If what you say is true, what's your response to Roberto's answer below? Is there any reason it shouldn't work or shouldn't be used?

Comment: @Eric: That answer is for adding calls to the log. I was addressing bullet #2; Roberto addressed bullet #1. My apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 10):

Regarding the first question, you can use this code to add new records to the existing Call logs content provider:

```
public static void insertPlaceholderCall(ContentResolver contentResolver, String number){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, number);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 0);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.NEW, 1);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, "");
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, 0);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, "");
    Log.d(TAG, "Inserting call log placeholder for " + number);
    contentResolver.insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

(Code taken from [Google Voice Callback for Android](http://code.google.com/p/gvcallback/))

Remember to add the permissions in the Manifest

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

Regarding the customization of the call logs database, I do not think is possible.

Comment: Can you help me a little bit? I did exactly same, insert is returning the URI of call log with id, but call log on my phone is not updated. It will be very helpful.