# Show a notification for missed VOIP calls

Tags: android, calllog

I did not find an answer to this question.
I have a VOIP application. I'm able to add a log about missed calls in the native call-log but the notification is not shown. 
Is there a way to ask the device native call log to show the notification?
I would not like to add my own notification because I want to be sure that the icon is always that one that the native call-log application would show for other calls.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144010/create-missed-call-notification) but there is no answer.
I'm using a code that is similar to that one shown in the previous post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just adding an entry in the call log db the notificatin will not be shown.
You need to add your on notification.
If you do not add your own notification, a notification will be shown only at phone start up if the call log is still there.

Answer (score 2):

Just for clarity:

You can still add your own notification, but use the android system build-in icons - these are the same icons that the built-in phonecall app is using. For example:

```
    Notification notification = new Notification();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.icon = android.R.drawable.stat_notify_missed_call;
```

This way you will always display  the icon that's characteristic for the specific Android OS version.

For more information check out the [Icon Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html), and especially in your case -[the status bar icons](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation (mainly copied from the android code):

```
private static void showMissedCallNotification(Context context, final Contact contact) {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // display the first line of the notification:
    // 1 missed call: call name
    // more than 1 missed call: <number of calls> + "missed calls"
    int titleResId;
    String expandedText;
    numberMissedCalls++;
    if (numberMissedCalls == 1) {
        titleResId = R.string.notification_missedCallTitle;
        expandedText = contact.getDisplayName();
    } else {
        titleResId = R.string.notification_missedCallsTitle;
        expandedText = context.getString(R.string.notification_missedCallsMsg,
                numberMissedCalls);
    }
    final PendingIntent callLogIntent = createCallLogIntent(context);
    // make the notification
    int id = android.R.drawable.stat_notify_missed_call;
    String ticker = context.getString(R.string.notification_missedCallTicker, contact.getDisplayNumber());
    long currentTime = Platform.timeProvider().getTime();
    Notification note = new Notification(id, ticker, currentTime);
    note.setLatestEventInfo(context, context.getText(titleResId), expandedText, callLogIntent);
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    // This intent will be called when the notification is dismissed.
    // It will take care of clearing the list of missed calls.
    note.deleteIntent = createClearMissedCallsIntent(context);

    //configureLedNotification(note);
    notificationManager.notify(MISSED_CALL_NOTIFICATION, note);
}

/**
 *  Returns an intent to be invoked when the missed call notification is clicked. 
 * @param context 
 */
private static PendingIntent createCallLogIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClearMissedCallsService.class);
    intent.setAction(ClearMissedCallsService.ACTION_OPEN_CALL_LOGS);
    return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
}

/**
 *  Returns an intent to be invoked when the missed call notification is cleared. 
 * @param context 
 */
private static PendingIntent createClearMissedCallsIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClearMissedCallsService.class);
    intent.setAction(ClearMissedCallsService.ACTION_CLEAR_MISSED_CALLS);
    return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
}

/*package */ static void cancelMissedCallNotification() {
    // reset the number of missed calls to 0.
    numberMissedCalls = 0;
    notificationManager.cancel(MISSED_CALL_NOTIFICATION);
}
```

and:

```
/**
 * Handles the intent to clear the missed calls that is triggered when a notification is dismissed.
 */
public class ClearMissedCallsService extends IntentService {
    /** This action is used to clear missed calls. */
    public static final String ACTION_CLEAR_MISSED_CALLS = "com.android.phone.intent.CLEAR_MISSED_CALLS";
    public static final String ACTION_OPEN_CALL_LOGS = "com.android.phone.intent.OPEN_CALL_LOGS";
public ClearMissedCallsService() {
        super(ClearMissedCallsService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Clear the list of new missed calls.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Calls.NEW, 0);
        StringBuilder where = new StringBuilder();
        where.append(Calls.NEW);
        where.append(" = 1 AND ");
        where.append(Calls.TYPE);
        where.append(" = ?");
        getContentResolver().update(Calls.CONTENT_URI, values, where.toString(),
                new String[]{ Integer.toString(Calls.MISSED_TYPE) });
        NativeCallLog.cancelMissedCallNotification();

        if (ACTION_OPEN_CALL_LOGS.equals(intent.getAction()))   {
            Intent intentOpenCallLogs = createOpenCallLogIntent();
            startActivity(intentOpenCallLogs);
        }

    }

    private static Intent createOpenCallLogIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls");
        return intent;
    }   

}
```

you also need to add this in the AndroidManifest

> ```
>     <service
>         android:exported="true"
>         android:name="yourpackage.ClearMissedCallsService" >
>         <intent-filter >
>             <action android:name="com.android.phone.intent.CLEAR_MISSED_CALLS" />
>         </intent-filter>
>         <intent-filter >
>             <action android:name="com.android.phone.intent.OPEN_CALL_LOGS" />
>         </intent-filter>            
>     </service>
> ```